# Return string between two substring perl

Tags: perl

I am using this perl code to return between string "11=1234.5755=3434.78=

This is returning me 123457, its removing decimal, how can i modify this code to 
$wanted=1234.57 and we can have multiple "=" in a line, I need generic soulion,to extract field between two "number="
Such as string between 55= and 8=

```
my ($wanted) = ($line =~ /11=(.*)55=/);
```

Comment: Are you sure? This looks like it will return `1234.57`.

Comment: No I checked its not working. Its eating up decimal

Comment: your code works for me too ... it is returning 1234.57

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($wanted) = $line =~ /(?:11|55)=(\d*[.]\d{0,2})/;
```

Comment: Thanks but it will not help if there is multiple = in a line, Line is "11=123.4555=23.45=" i want number between 11= and 55= or 55= and 5=

Comment: Thank mpapec, seems to be some issue with your code. Its not working

Comment: @Whitesand can you give examples when it is not working?